# Where do I find the the Home Run Baseball Bat?

Tags: dead-island

I have been looking on the game for 2 weeks or so, and really need this weapon in my arsenal. Where is it ?

Answer (score 3):

From the [wiki](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Homerun_Baseball_Bat) :

> It is created using the *Developer's No. 2 Craft*, which can be crafted at a workbench with $10,000, 5 Diamonds, and a Battery.

The Developer's No.2 Craft is obtained by placing the [Green Skull](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Skull) in its correct location.

The skull is found on the south end of the Resort Map, about halfway between Bunker 06 and the City Tunnel Gas Station.

> From the bunker, the player can follow the road marked on the map that would lead them to the gas station or westward. Following the road from the bunker, the player will see a small boat. The player must go past the small boat, into the cave, and exit the other side. There, the player will see a larger capsized boat. Next to the boat will be a rocky cliff with several palm trees growing from it. The skull is at the top of the cliff where the player must jump over a bush onto the rocks to the top. It will be lying in a box next to a metal chest.[image: green skull location]

Altar for the Green Skull :

> In Chapter 7, the Supermarket has an aisle full of teddy bears with a green floor. There is also a flashlight shining on a bear. Use the flashlight to see the green arrow pointing on a bear.

Comment: OMG thank u soo much I been hunting for an answer for weeks and u are thy saviour XD

Comment: Again, feel free to mark it as resolved :)